# Removing negative values from axis

Tags: java, javafx-8, bar-chart, linechart, axis-labels

I have a `BarChart` and a `LineChart`.

The possible values go from negative(-) to positive(+). How would I only display the positive axis-labels? As in only remove the numbers.

Should I make a custom Chart or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking through the NumberAxis source, I found out that the DefaultFormatter class inside the NumberAxis class is accountable for this. So overriding the toString method of it was enough.

```
myAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(neerslagAxis) {
            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {
                if ((double) object < 0) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return ("" + object).replace(".0", "");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set Y-Axis lower bound to 0 and disable an auto-ranging:

```
    yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    yAxis.setLowerBound(0);
```

Here is an example:

[image: chart]

```
public class FXChart extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart
                = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //populating the series with data
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, -14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, -24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, -36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, -45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, -17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        yAxis.setLowerBound(0);

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```